# Centering an <img> vertically inside of a table <td>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to center these images vertically inside of the table without having to edit the picture so that they are the same size. Tried a few things... I know whenever I want to center something horizontally I use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` So I thought maybe the same would apply here, but with top and bottom, but no dice.

**EDIT:** Here is another idea... would it be possible to set up a javascript to run as the page is opened to position all of the text spans as low as the lowest span in that row?
Just a thought... let me know what you think

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Here is the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/58u4g/1/

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `valign="middle"` for that cell, but it depends on the overall row size.

Comment: @MahanGM Didn't work. Where would I have to put the `vertical-align`?

Comment: I don't think `vertical-align` on the table cell will work in this context because the `<a>` tags wrapped around images define the heights of table cells.

Comment: You have to apply it to your cell tag: `<td valign="middle"></td>`. As I said, it depends on the overall row height, if there is no enough space to spare, then there is no vertical aligning.

Comment: well I know that if I take out `display: inline-block` It does exactly that, but then my text is messed up.

Comment: `HTML5` doesn't support `valign` attribute, so avoid it if you can

Comment: @gwillie so do you think the only reasonable and right way to do this is to just create same size images?

Answer (score 1):

CSS vertical alignment is different across all browsers - especially if you want to keep the text in the same cell.

I recommend creating a fixed height block for the images to go in, and using a vertical align hack to get the image vertically centered within that div (I know, hacks are bad).

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/58u4g/8/

**Vertical align hack**: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Relevant CSS:

```
.valign {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    #position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.valign > span {
    display: block;
    #position: absolute;
    #top: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.valign> span > span {
    display: block;
    #position: relative;
    #top: -50%;
}

#posiflex_directory td .image {
    height: 160px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Interesting response, however not too sure I want to go with a hack on this one. Was hoping for a simpler approach... at this point I am thinking that I will need to create images that are the same sizes... stupid mozilla ruined everything with the caption spans... so I had to change it to `display: inline-block` and that is causing the images to 'stick' to the top.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it differently for the sake of separating elements to have better control over them, even though my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rf9xT/) is not clean and is a mash of your sample plus the bits I through in :)

```
<table id="posiflex_directory">
    <tr class="theimgs">
    <td>
        <a href="../posiflex/tx_overview.aspx" id="posiTXIcon">
            <span class="valigner"></span>
            <img height="125" src="https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/posiflex/images/home_icons/tx-4200.png" width="200"/>
        </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="../posiflex/cd_overview.aspx" id="posiCDIcon">
            <span class="valigner"></span>

          <img height="103" src="https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/posiflex/images/home_icons/CR6300.png" width="200"/>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="imgtext"><a href="../posiflex/tx_overview.aspx" id="posiTXIcon"><span>TX Fan-Free Series</span></a></td>
    <td class="imgtext"><a href="../posiflex/cd_overview.aspx" id="posiCDIcon"><span>Cash Drawers</span></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>



#posiflex_directory {
    text-align: center;
}

#posiflex_directory a {
    color: inherit;
    position: relative;
}

#posiflex_directory td {
    border: solid 1px;
}

#posiflex_directory .theimgs {
    width: 215px;
    height: 225px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px;
}

#posiflex_directory span {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top:100%;
    bottom: 5px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}

img {
    border: solid 1px;
}
.valigner {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.imgtext{
    height:40px;
}
```

Comment: So I liked your idea, however it can be done much simpler (you don't even need `vertical-align`). See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58u4g/10/
If this is what I end up going with I'll give you the check.

Comment: Would it also be possible to maybe create a Javascript to run when the page opens and set the text spans as low as the lowest? because they are positioned absolute.